# Is this proof for the divisibility constraint $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ correct, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number given in *Eulerian form*, i.e. $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Define the GCDs
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$$
$$H = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
and
$$I = \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)),$$
where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

Note that
$$G \times H = I^2$$
$$G \mid I$$
$$I \mid H$$
and that
$$H = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$

Let
$$J = \frac{I}{G} = \frac{H}{I} = \sqrt{\frac{H}{G}}.$$

It can be shown that
$$J = \frac{n}{\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2, n)}.$$

---

Suppose that
$$J = \frac{n}{\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2, n)} = \frac{n}{d}, \tag{1}$$
where $d$ is a divisor of $n$.

Note that $(1)$ is true if and only if $\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2, n) = d$.

Notice that
$$\frac{Jnd}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = H.$$

But we also know that
$$H = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$

Hence, under the given assumption, we get
$$\sigma(n^2) = \frac{Jnd}{\sigma(q^k)/2}\cdot{q^k}$$
$$n = Jd.$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd\left(Jd,\frac{Jnd}{\sigma(q^k)/2}\cdot{q^k}\right)$$
Since $\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2, n) = d$, then $d \mid \sigma(q^k)/2$ holds.

Since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k)/2)=1$, we consider three cases:

**Case (1):** $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid d$

This case implies that $d = \sigma(q^k)/2$, and therefore that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ holds.

**Case (2):** $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$

No problem.

**Case (3):** $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid J$

$$\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid J \implies J = e\cdot\sigma(q^k)/2 \text{ for some } e \implies \frac{n}{\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2, n)} = e\cdot\sigma(q^k)/2$$
$$\implies n = e\cdot{\sigma(q^k)/2}\cdot{\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2, n)} \implies \sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$$

---

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Does this proof suffice?  I have doubts if the list of three cases is complete, as I am aware that it may happen that either $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid Jn$, $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid Jd$, or $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid nd$ also hold.

---

**Update (Added on March 26, 2023 - 15:22 PM (Manila time))**

The condition $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid Jd$ is equivalent to $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ since $Jd = n$.

That leaves us (???) with the following three further cases to consider:
$\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid Jn$, $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid nd$, or $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid Jnd$.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Comment: Lastly, since $H \geq 3$, then it may as well happen that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid Jnd$.

Comment: I noticed that if I could show
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=Jd=n$$
then it would follow that $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, which is true if and only if $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ since
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=2q^k n^2$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n} = \frac{q^k n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$